# Does anybody use an external battery for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, battery

Do USB battery packs for iPhones work well?

For example, is it true that I can charge my iPhone 4 up to 6 times my iphone with one?

For example this product:

[image: iCarrier charger - IMP120d]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - and most people I know fit into strongly preferring a rechargeable solution when they use the device regularly to extend power on the go.

Those that use the device occasionally or on long trips seem to gravitate to an inexpensive sled for AA batteries and carry a mix of expensive lithium cells and typical non-rechargeable cells.